# HTTP Request - HTML Table Import/Select Into SQL Server Table CLR or TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, t-sql, sqlclr

**Background:**
First, I think it's important to note that this is a SQL Express Server running on a development machine. The server is only used as a feed for various excel reports.

Due to operational silos I don't have direct access to all the databases that store the data I need. What I'm currently doing is using Excel VBA querytable to download a SSRS table, import to access, then picking up the access tables using a linked server.

**Question:**

I've modified this CLR code slightly to pass the SSRS authorization. I'm just unsure on how/if I can return the http request in a fashion that let's me import into a table on the SQL server.

I then would set up a windows task to automatically run the sql/grab the data daily, removing the vba/access db from the process.

If you have any tips or suggestions on alternate methods, I'm not too concerned on how I get there. Thanks for your help!

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Data.SqlTypes
Imports System.Net
Public Class FavoriteCLRs
<Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction()>
Public Shared Function CLR_WebQuery(ByVal URL As String) As String
    Dim cookieContainer As CookieContainer = New CookieContainer()

    Dim myCredentials As New NetworkCredential("user", "password")
    ' Create a WebRequest with the specified URL. 
    Dim request As HttpWebRequest = CType(HttpWebRequest.Create(URL), HttpWebRequest)
    myCredentials.Domain = "domain"
    request.Credentials = myCredentials

    request.Timeout = 10000
    request.Method = "GET"
    request.KeepAlive = True
    request.AllowAutoRedirect = True
    request.PreAuthenticate = True
    request.CookieContainer = cookieContainer
    Using response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
        Using dataStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
            Using reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
                Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
                Return responseFromServer
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
    request = Nothing
End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the format of the data coming back from SSRS? Is it XML? Without knowing more about the exact format it is hard to give detailed advice, but I can mention a couple of things to consider:

1. If you want to keep with a scalar function, you need to parse the SSRS output with T-SQL. If the data coming from SSRS is XML then you can do that rather easily via the `.nodes()` function.
2. Whether the data coming back is XML or delimited or even an HTML table, text parsing will generally be more efficiently handled by .NET. So, rather than returning `responseFromServer`, after the `request = Nothing` line, parse the output into rows and change the function to be a Table-Valued Function (TVF) so that you can pass back a table. Then you can very easily populate the table in SQL Server using:

   ```sql
   INSERT INTO dbo.SomeTable (Col1, Col2, ...)
     SELECT Field1, Field2,...
     FROM   dbo.CLR_WebQuery(N'http://some/URL.aspx?stuff');
   ```

Comment: srutzky, thanks for your response. I actually found out that I could use the SSRS parameters "&rs:command=render&rs:format=csv" which made the whole process a lot easier. I went a little bit of a different route and ended up writing a vb console app that can be run off windows services. I've marked you as the answer because I think this would have worked as well.